# weird behavior: less rows are scanned without index on the columns in where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a table called `A` which store the longitude and latitude data. And there's a query to get rows whose location is within some geo rectangle, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE A.longitude > -121.276052
    AND A.longitude < -110.159143
    AND A.latitude > 32.802275
    AND A.latitude < 38.335916
ORDER BY A.id
LIMIT 100
```

Table `A` only have index on id column, which is also the primary key. I would expect a big amount of rows be scanned because of no index on `longitude` and `latitude` columns. However, it turns out it only scans 100 rows from the output of explain.

(Also I verified the ids of output rows are not accidentally the smallest. They're actually in the middle of id range)

Why come mysql can accurately identifies the 100 rows with id index only?

Comment: It's worth using the `BETWEEN` clause in cases like this.

Comment: @tadman ya, but I don't think it'll make any difference. My point here is why this query only scans 100 rows with id index only.

Comment: The first 100 rows happen to match the conditions in the `WHERE` clause, so MySQL stops scanning.

Comment: @GordonLinoff nope. I commented on your answer.

Comment: rows in the EXPLAIN output is an estimate. Maybe the optimizer is estimating that it's only going to need to look at 100 rows, based on the LIMIT. Maybe the optimizer doesn't have a good estimate about how selective the predicates are, because there's no index stats. the optimizer is being "optimistic" that the first 100 rows it looks at are going to satisfy the predicates. (If the predicates were highly selective, dba would have created an index).[http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#explain_rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#explain_rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer:** `EXPLAIN's` "Rows" cannot be trusted.

**The long answer:**

The following can be trusted:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

If you see 100 reads (or maybe 99 or 101), then it is nice and efficient.  But I suspect you will see a larger number, but less than the number of rows in the table.  However, if there are fewer than 100 rows in that bounding box, it will have to scan the entire table.

**Partial speedup**

```
INDEX(latitude)
```

will help some.  That is generally "good enough" for medium-sized lat-lng tables.  This should be an "order of magnitude" faster than what you have.

A "late fetch" may help a little bit more:

```
SELECT *
    FROM A
    JOIN ( SELECT id FROM A WHERE lat... AND lng... ) AS x USING(id)
-- and have this "covering" index for the subquery:
INDEX(latitude, longitude, id)
```

**Further speedup**

If you have a large table, then the solution becomes more complex; I discuss how to use [partitioning to get a 2D index](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng).  It includes stored routines that are another order of magnitude faster.

Comment: [Example of my algorithm](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134028/select-the-minimum-of-a-calculated-distance-value-without-sorting) (in the answer).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what the question is.  In your query, MySQL is scanning the index for the `order by` -- it is getting all rows in `id` order.  Then, it is looking up each row in the data pages to see if it matches the `where` clause.

Presumably, the first 100 rows in the index match the `where` clause.  Hence, MySQL can stop scanning after 100 rows.

Comment: ya, that's my first guess too. I also mentioned in my question. I verified the ids of the returned rows. they're not the smallest.